# CiviCRM Report - Sorting DB error

Tags: civireport, error, database

when I'm preparing a report (Event Participants) through CiviCRM Report module and I want to sort the results by anything (age, name, etc) I am getting a fatal error: `DB ERROR: No such field`

I'm currently on **Drupal 7.69** and **CiviCRM 5.20.**

Here is the full log of this issue:

```
     [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(208): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(987): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...")
#3 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...")
#4 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1920): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...", "1055 ** Expression #21 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains ...")
#7 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1229): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...")
#9 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2416): DB_common->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...")
#10 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...")
#11 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(435): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...")
#12 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1428): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...", TRUE)
#13 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(3076): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...")
#14 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(3561): CRM_Report_Form->buildRows("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...", (Array:0))
#15 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Event/ParticipantListing.php(616): CRM_Report_Form->postProcess()
#16 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(495): CRM_Report_Form_Event_ParticipantListing->postProcess()
#17 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Submit.php(74): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#18 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Submit->perform(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Event_ParticipantListing), "submit")
#19 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Event_ParticipantListing), "submit")
#20 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("submit")
#21 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(114): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#22 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Instance.php(90): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Report_Form_Event_ParticipantListing", NULL, (Array:0))
#23 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284): CRM_Report_Page_Instance->run((Array:4), NULL)
#24 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#25 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#26 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#27 /var/www/html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("report", "instance", "26")
#28 /var/www/html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#29 {main}
```

Has anyone come across such an issue? Is my database missing a table header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the report but you can work around it by turning off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY on the server. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-configuration

Comment: Thanks! It works, but only partially - I am still not able to sort the report by the age of the participants (I can show the column "Age", but in sorting options, I have a choice called "Sort by Age in the day of the event" (not "Age"). Here is the error I'm getting:

`#6 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_so...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'contact_civireport.age_at_event' in 'field list'")`

Comment: Ah yet another bug! Can you file a report at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/report/issues?

Comment: Already done that, thanks! https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/report/issues/26